# Facebook App Events for React Native App

Tags: facebook, react-native

I would like to use Facebook App Events for my React Native App. I could see help for only native iOS and native Android. Please could you direct me to use Facebook App Events for React Native App?

Thanks,
Babu

Comment: There's the library [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk). Worth a look?

Comment: Got it thanks @TheLazySloth !!

Comment: Lol Babu........

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Babs you can use react-native-fbsdk which gives a functionality of having App Events in it .
Here is the link for more help :- https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was applying it to one of the apps I was developing and found a part of the Facebook Developers documentation that talks about how to apply using examples that is available at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android/?translation#examples

But now you can use an event capture which refers to using the app to capture the number of daily hits.

⚠ Important just add don't need to delete a function similar to this example

```
// was triggered in android/app/src/main/java/com/your-app-name/Main Application.java file

  @Override public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
```